# Google Spreadsheet array not working

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I'm not sure what I missed as my arrays are not working.  Here's the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_pPSRjEnKv10mDR8LICVvVv7jgXVBJ1aWZ8KrdEIKd4/edit#gid=0

Please check highlighted in green.

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_pPSRjEnKv10mDR8LICVvVv7jgXVBJ1aWZ8KrdEIKd4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure how to explain why it doesn't work because there are a list of things - various ways in which array formula operates - but I would like to suggest to you to use regexextract instead of search: I created the two formulas for is profile and is live, hopefully I can try to explain what the pieces do:

in column Y:

```
=arrayformula(if(arrayformula(if(istext(regexextract(C2:C,"automated")),1,0))+arrayformula(if(or(istext(regexextract(C2:C,"clinic profile")),istext(regexextract(C2:C,"dr profile"))),1,0))=2,1,0))
```

in column Z:

```
=arrayformula(if(Y2:Y=1,if(istext(regexextract(C2:C,"live")),1,0),0))
```

Basically instead of using the search - regexextract will find your search terms anywhere in that text and it works well with array formula, then using the if and istext to give it a true of false value of 1 or 0.

if the value is not found in that corresponding cell, it would in theory return #N/A if it was in an individual cell - but if the value is there the regexextract would return that value to you, which why the istext works

By the way if Im confusing you , then if you want to change your sheet to be editable by anyone I can jump in and show you what I did..

Comment: Im in there adding the formulas - all the columns i have edited i changed to a shade of blue

Comment: Another issue is to convert countifs to array:

=countifs('raw-premium-doctors'!C:C,$AC2,'raw-premium-doctors'!J:J,"FALSE")

Comment: I dont see a sheet called raw-premium-doctors on there so how are you countingif on it? but regardless array would be =arrayformula(countifs('raw-premium-doctors'!C2:C,$AC2:AC,'raw-premium-doctors'!J2:J,"FALSE"))

Comment: here it is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_pPSRjEnKv10mDR8LICVvVv7jgXVBJ1aWZ8KrdEIKd4/edit#gid=1953450358

I tried and the array is not working

Comment: Thanks Aurielle for the help. :)

Comment: btw, is there an array formula that append dates? Meaning if a new day comes in, a new date is appended.